# What thread type do standard sprinkler nozzles have?

Tags: sprinkler-system

I am assembling a sprinkler system for my gardens and decided to use [these standard lawn sprinkler nozzles](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Orbit-15-ft-Adjustable-Spray-Head-Nozzle/3606706) as they are pretty cheap and seem to do what I want, however I can't find anywhere what the thread type is on them.

I contacted Orbit and their rep told me they are a half inch NPT thread, but after purchasing and receiving them they are definitely not.  The diameter is smaller than a 1/2" NPT and larger than a 1/4" and the thread is finer than both and appears to have no taper like a NPT thread does.

Does anybody know what thread these things use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not proprietary.  Its a standard straight pipe thread.  SAE J1926.  Go to a hydraulic hose shop.  They use them all the time.

Comment: https://www.goodyearrubberproducts.com/files/parker/parkertubecatalog4300/parker%20tube%20catalog%204300examin1.page477.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I’ll chime in - I think the thread size you’re looking for is 15mm.. as far as the thread density I think it’s 32 per inch.. it’s a confusing world of different standards and nomenclature, which I’ve only scratched the surface of, but these are standardized across the major manufacturers- except Toro which I think has female thread instead of male like the others. Some threads, especially with PVC fittings, are tapered to narrow at the end which facilitates easy connections… (warning! Do not ever, ever tighten tapered thread connections to the full depth. Always leave 2-3 threads showing because as the male part widens it will split the female part causing leaks. I see this all the time when I have to renovate irrigation manifolds its super rookie and annoying)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is commonly called a “shrub adapter”. (Put this into Amazon).

This shrub adapter is 1/2 inch fnpt to screw into the 1/2 inch mnpt riser tube and converts to a male thread that you can screw your nozzle (female thread) into.

These shrub adapters are also made to sweat unto copper, but are considerably more expensive, ($7 vs $1)  if you can even find them.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this info as well to get a die in an attempt to recut the threads on a riser tube.
The from a thread gauge and a caliper, I think it is 5/8" x 28UN.

The thread gauge pretty clearly indicates 28 threads per inch.
The outside measurement matches 5/8 according to this table.
https://torqbolt.com/28un-unified-thread-dimensions-specifications

Answer (score 0):

Any of the dozen or so types I have are 1/2 NPS, maybe a couple of 3/4 . Some male some female. Smaller than 1/2 sounds like a drip irrigation system. Some heads come as a body( 1/2 NPS)and a separate spray nozzle, these spray nozzles have smaller than 1/2 threads.

Comment: These are the head type that separates from the body.  I am fairly sure that they are not NPS as I believe NPS threads have the same pitch as a corresponding NPT thread and the threads on the ones i have are much finer than even a 1/4" NPT.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not designed to be used on its own**.

It is a replacement spray head nozzle for an in-ground pop-up sprinkler. The thread is not some standard thread like NPT, it is a proprietary thread that is on the rising tube of a pop-up sprinkler by specific manufacturers.

Return it to whoever sold it to you and buy a spray head designed to be used on its own; it will likely be called a "shrub sprayer head" or something like that.

[image]:

Comment: I know it's not *designed* to be used on its own.  But if I know the thread dimensions I can easily buy or make an adapter.  Like I said, these things were cheaper than the alternatives by a fair amount which is why I opted for them.  It's also not really propriatery as it's used by multiple manufacturers, so I am super puzzled as to why it is seemingly impossible to find the specifications on it.

Comment: It is not a "standard" plumbing thread and you will not find fittings or adapters that will work with it. It **was** proprietary (Rain Bird) until these later manufacturers (Hunter, Orbit) adopted it. Do yourself a favor and spend $1.00 more and get the sprayers that are designed to screw directly to pipe risers, these are just pop-up sprinkler nozzles, not a complete product, but a *part*.

Comment: It's a standard in that multiple companies use it.  And for my application comparable solutions are more than $1 in price difference, I also am not super keen on waiting another couple weeks for more parts to arrive.  I can easily make an adapter if none really exists if I know what the thread is but I don't have the capability to measure the thread myself given the geometry of the inside of the part.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm facing a similar question.  I have an outdoor spigot with threads that are approx. 0.910mm apart and rain bird threads that are approx. .735mm apart (used calipers to VERY approximately measure).

In my spare part bag I also have a **SPEARS AP-106 adapter** that has the rain bird compatible threads on one side and the garden spigot compatible threads on the other.  It's not a complete solution but it might help you on your journey.

Comment: Apparently there is a difference between "pipe thread" and "hose thread." gl :-D